# lvs shows Input/Output error

Tags: linux, lvm

I am unable to figure out where is the exact problem on my disk. as per the screenshot it says that there is Input/Output error.

[image]

Comment: I/O error is a potential indication of HW failure.

Comment: But there isn't any HW failure, everything is working smooth.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `dmesg`, there may be some clues there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicated is happening at 4 different offsets (sectors) of your `/dev/sdao` device:

1. 0
2. 4096
3. 75161862144
4. 75161919488

How you determine that it is not a hardware failure is beyond me as it is most likely the case.